# Does ContentResolver perform IO operations?

Tags: android

When I get the file type based on the Uri, does the content resolver need to perform a read operation (to read the first bytes of the file?)?

```
suspend fun importFile(uri: Uri) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
    val type = contentResolver.getType(uri)
    val ext = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(type)
    Log.d("FILE", "$uri $type $ext")
}
```

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/12 application/pdf pdf
```

Here, the content resolver can tell the file (coming from OPEN_DOCUMENT intent) is a pdf without needing a file extension.

I am wondering if I should be wrapping these function calls in a `withContext(Dispatchers.IO`. The same goes for using a cursor.

```
fun displayName(uri: Uri?): String? {
    if (uri == null) return null

    val cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
    cursor?.use {
        if (it.moveToFirst()) {
            val columnIndex = it.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
            if (columnIndex != -1) {
                val displayName =  it.getString(columnIndex)
                return File(displayName).nameWithoutExtension
            }
        }
    }

    return null
}
```

Comment: `does the content resolver need to perform a read operation (to read the first bytes of the file?)?` No. The getType() call is forwarded to the content provider which delivers a type.

Comment: @blackapps I thought files had a header that describe its content and type, but the content provider probably has a mapping from uri to file path with extension and relies on the file extension to tell the type. `/sdcard/Download/the-complete-sherlock-holmes.pdf` If the mapping is stored in a database, wouldn't the content provider need to perform a read operation? `cursor.use` is needed to get the file name, which makes me think there is a stream that needs to be closed.

Comment: Not all files have headers that describe content. And how a provider reacts to a get type call is to the provider. The provider can do what it wants. Looking at extension is common i think.

Comment: Why are you worried if a provider closes a stream or a cursor or not? Or whatever? Nobody will blame your app querying a provider.

Comment: @blackapps I wasn't sure if the main thread will be blocked by an IO operation and whether we were supposed to wrap the function call in a `suspend` function with `Dispatchers.IO`. (stream = IO)